# How to export C# documentation to a documentation wiki?

Tags: c#, documentation, wiki

I am looking for something that will iterate over our model and extract each objects properties in order to build a documentation wiki.  Is there a tool out there which will do such a thing?

Basically I do not want to have to extract all of our documentation out of the projects by hand.

Answer (score 2):

[sandcastle](http://www.sandcastledocs.com/) builds webpages, but they aren't editable as a wiki.  Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?