# Generate wiki documentation for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

Is there some tool that can generate wiki pages from a C# documentation?

Comment: Could be. If so, I apologize and retract my comments.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1596198/340760

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Document!X](http://www.innovasys.com/products/dx2010/overview.aspx) from Innovasys is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

[Help Server](http://help.x-tensive.com/##HelpServer/External/User%20Guide.htm) can publish Sandastle chm files to web.

Answer (score 0):

There was a documentation tool for .NET Framework 1.x and 2.0 called Sand Castle; not sure if it is still being maintained. If you Google for Sand Castle you should be able to find it.